# スクレイピングのコンソールでのつまり

Tags: ruby-on-rails

railsでスクレイピングを行うようにコードを書いています。
コンソールでスクレイピングを実行したら、

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `current_page' for Scraping:Class
from /Users/mooovi/app/models/scraping.rb:13:in `movie_urls'
```

とエラーメッセージが出ました。
current_pageが定義されていない、と出ていますが
どうしてそう言われるのかわかりません。
scraping.rbに

```
class Scraping
    def self.movie_urls
    agent = Mechanize.new
    links = []
    next_url = "/now/"

   while true
    current_page=agent.get("http://eiga.com"+next_url)
    elements = current_page.search('.m_unit h3 a')
    elements.each do |ele|
      links << ele.get_attribute('href')
    end

    next_link = current_page.at('.next_page')
    next_url = next_link.get_attribute('href')

    unless next_url
     break
    end

      links.each do |link|
      get_product('http://eiga.com' + link)
      end
  end

    def self.get_product(link)
    agent = Mechanize.new
    page = agent.get(link)
    title = page.at('.moveInfoBox h1').inner_text
    image_url = page.at('.pictBox img')[:src] if page.at('.pictBox img')
    director= page.at('.f span').inner_text if page.at('.f span')
    detail= page.at('.outline p').inner_text
    open_date= page.at('.opn_date strong').inner_text if page.at('.opn_date strong')

    product=Product.where(:title => title, :image_url => image_url).first_or_initialize
    product.director=director
    product.detail=detail
    product.open_date=open_date
    product.save
    end
end
```

のようにコードを記載しました。

```
current_page=agent.get("http://eiga.com"+next_url)
```

の所でcurrent_pageを定義しているのですが。。。

Comment: 全文を正確に貼り付けていますか？ 今のままでは end が足りないので、コードを整形して、再編集してみてください。

Answer (score -2, accepted):

current_page を @current_page にすべて置換してみればよいかもです。

Comment: ブロックローカル変数をブロック外からアクセスするためにインスタンス変数に変更するのは明らかに誤った解決方法です。

Comment: たしかにそうですね。失礼しました。
シンタックスエラーになるところを直して実行してみたところこれといって当該のエラーはでなかったので、もう一度ソースを確認していただければと思います。